# Значение типа"const *char" нельзя присвоить сущности типа"*char"

Tags: c++

Нужно объяснение почему вот так делать нельзя???

```
    #include<iostream>
    using std::cin;
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    void ChangeValue(char name[])
    {

        name = "Jackson";//ERROR
    }
    int main()
    {
        const int size = 10;
        char name[size];
        ChangeValue(name);
        return 0;
    }
```

Я знаю что `="Jackson"`-это константый строковый литерал.

ВОПРОС: Как можно в функции изменить значение массива char-ов `name[]`

Comment: В этой функции `char name[]` - это не массив, а указатель, `char *` (это проблема в языке). Массивы в С++ присваивать вообще нельзя (тоже проблема в языке), а на строке `name = "Jackson";` будет попытка присвоить указателю объект без const квалификатора указатель на объект с const квалификатором, что запрещено (ну хоть что-то, имеющее смысл). Для копирования строк и массивов есть куча функций - всякие strcpy memcpy. А вообще вместо C-style массивов следует использовать `std::array`, а для строк - `std::string`.

Comment: @user7860670 Значит так как имя массива по сути указатель на первый элемент,то я пытаюсь присвоить `Jackson` первому элементу,я правильно понимаю???

Comment: Нет, имя массива - это не указатель на первый элемент. `char name[]` в аргументе функции - это не массив, а указатель. А `"Jackson"` - как раз массив. И вы пытаетесь присвоить указателю на `char` строковый литерал, который в этом контексте преобразуется в указатель на `char const`.

Comment: @user7860670 Спасибо большое за ответ.Только сейчас доперло)))

Comment: [Проблема с const char](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459656), [значение типа “const char*” нельзя использовать...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/946374), [E0144 значение типа “const char *” нельзя использовать...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/908800), [Присваивание символа const char *](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/202856), [Значение типа const char* нельзя присвоить сущности типа char*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/864245).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Массивы в Си/Си++ не передаются копированием в списке аргументов. Аргумент `char name[]` рассматривается как указатель на первый элемент массива `char * name`.

Строка в программе `"Jackson"` это массив константных букв, а когда вы указателю присваиваете массив, то массив букв автоматически преобразовывается в указатель на первую букву. И ошибка происходит из-за попытки присваивать указатель указателю другого типа.

Чтобы копировать массивы функций нет, для каждого типа всё индивидуально. Копировать строки можно с помощью `strcpy` или `strncpy`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstring>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
void ChangeValue(int size,char name[])
{
  strncpy(name,"Jackson",size);
}
int main()
{
    const int size = 10;
    char name[size];
    ChangeValue(size,name);
    std::cout<<"name = '"<<name<<'\''<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Все понял,спасибо огромное за ответ,наверное все же лучше использовать `std::array` .Как думаете?

Comment: P.S Извините мне мое любопытство,может вопрос не по теме,сколько вы изучали(-ете) "кресты".И много ли книг прочитали,и какую выделите как маст-хэв?Можете не отвечать если не хотите,я пойму.Может этот вопрос задать отдельно,но думаю опять минусовать будут.

Comment: Чем проще типы, тем понятнее прога. Использование классов ведёт к абстрактности и теряется связь почему прога не пашет и так медленно. Всё на любителя.

Comment: @D1slav [Книги и учебные ресурсы по С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263). Общеизвестно, что C++ можно освоить за [21 день](https://habr.com/ru/post/87737/) :)

Comment: @wololo Если так,то конечно получится выучить за 21 день)))А про материалы я уже читал этот вопрос,честно:не внушает доверия,но книги пересмотрю.

Comment: @D1slav по книгам сложно сказать, у каждого своё мнение + зависит от начальной подготовки. Лично я бы обратил внимание на: 1) Липпман, Язык программирования C++, 2) Страуструп, Язык программирования C++, 3) Джосаттис, Стандартная библиотека C++.

Comment: @wololo Спасибо за посоветованные книги,только Страуструпа страшно))И,да вы правы у каждого на любую книгу своё мнение.